# NSDocumentController noteNewRecentDocumentURL(_:) equivalent for MacCatalyst

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst, document-based

I recently built an app with UIKit for iOS, iPadOS and macOS.

This app opens files (it's a code editor). When a file is opened from Finder, it appears in the recent menu, but when a file is opened from the app menu, it does not.

I wanted to use `NSDocumentController noteNewRecentDocumentURL(_:)` to add it manually, but it is not available in Mac Catalyst.

Any method to add a file to the recent menu on Mac Catalyst?

The documentation for macOS (available only in AppKit, not catalyst): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514967-notenewrecentdocumenturl